# NPM Package works but import not found by IDE

Tags: reactjs, npm, package

i love working with npm and my first package is working fine. In my IDE (Webstorm) when importing my package it highlights and says "Cannot resolve symbol" (well but it works).

But when using the suggested import on missing classes it imports it also wrong.

Within my project with working import:

```
import {APIRequest} from "nsfw-connector";
```

Not working:

```
import APIRequest from "nsfw-connector/src/APIRequest";
```

I believe my problem is in my npm package and how its exported.

```
index.js
module.exports = {
    APIRequest: require('./APIRequest').default,
    ...
};
```

The corresponding class

```
export class APIRequest {
    ...
}
export default APIRequest;
```

Maybe the is a samaritan who knows what my stupid fault is.

[IDE error highligt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56GFq.png)

The GitHub Project: https://github.com/NilsBaumgartner1994/NSFW-Connector

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue. We have a npm package and when importing it like:
`import {SomeComponent} from "our-package"`. It works but I do not get intellisense. It is because the *component* is exported from within `/src/index.js` and thus, appending `/src` to the end of the *package* path erases the warnings.
I also tried to put `"main": "src/index.js"` into the `package.json` and import components like I used to originally but to no avail.
Another fix I tried and worked (sort of) was to place that `/src/index.js` into the root of the *project* that solved warnings and intellisense started to work as well (as it is the default value for aforementioned `"main"` field in `package.json` (interestingly enough) [npmjs docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#main)